# Efficently display results from multiple joins

Tags: sql, jpa, join

In a JPA project I need to display a table whose data comes from 5 related entities.
Without JPA I could write a sql query which joins the 5 database tables together and filters according to some criteria.
Suppose that the fields involved in the filtering criteria are only those of  the first entity.
Using JPA I can load filtered instances of the first entity and navigate through the properties till the final entity.
My concern is that way the number of queries to the database can explode if I cannot use or do a mistake with the fecttype=eager annotation.
Which is the best approach in such cases ? 
I would like to have a strict control over the sql queries that will be executed, so I can optimize them, but if I write the sql query with the joins by hand do I have to use the 'old' resultset to retrive the data ?

Comment: Can you create View's on your Database?

Comment: yes, I can. Unfortunately the filtering criteria are dynamic, so I cannot put them inside a view, or simply I cannot how to do it. My concern is about the filtering process: if I first create the view and then filter it I have to join a very large table, not only the rows I'm interested in. Please read comment on the answer below too.

Comment: Ok, to use static views and dynamic querys together is may risky. Can you offer more informations about framework or database?

Comment: I use MySql db and GlassFish v3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA's built-in query language, the JPQL, can't you? (It does have a JOIN operator for sure.) Be aware though that this is not standard SQL, only something similar, so read the JPQL docs thoroughly. Yes, this is still plain text queries embedded in Java code, which is a shame, but hey, that's how far Java can go supporting the development process.

The main advantage here is that you get entity objects as the result of your queries - although you still need to cast them from Object. You can also use the objects (records) and their member variables (attributes) directly in the query string, so this is a step up from good old JDBC.

Alternatively you could also choose the Criteria API, but frankly, my experiences were not very good with it. The syntax is quite horrible and you basically end up building the low-level query yourself. This is clearly Java at its worst... but at least Strings containing queries can be eliminated from the code. I'm not sure it's worth it though.

Check this page for more information and examples:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjise.html

Comment: I agree about the criteria API, a real nightmare for newbie. My idea is the following: create a 'freak' view with very few rows just to create an entity from it (lets call it summarydata). Create a JPQL query with joins and add dynamic filtering conditions. Cast it to summarydata and dispaly in a jsf h:datatable. It should work, shouldn't it ?